# Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

i'm using create-react-app with PWA and just can't work notifications api :(

this error:

```
Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined
```

My code

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
    console.log("Notification permission status:", status);
  });

  async function displayNotification() {
    if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
       await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(reg => {
         reg.showNotification("Go go")
       });
    }
  }
```

I didn't understand the error

Answer (score 3):

you cannot both await and use then. You can only use then on promises. And if you await, you resolve your promise.

you can do either :

```
async function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
     const reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
     reg.showNotification("Go go");
  }
}
```

or :

```
function displayNotification() {
  if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
     navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(reg => {
       reg.showNotification("Go go");
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: So I just did a test on the build works normal, but local is not rolling ... I think it's because the serviceWorker.js file is not in the public folder. but it's a kick only.